# non-UI event loop that can wait for a last UI window to close

Tags: c++, signals, cross-platform, event-loop

I'm working on a small framework for cross platform applications (sure, for academic purposes) and it needs to handle non-UI and UI programs gracefully. I'm currently investigating if having an OS message/event loop per window is possible. At this point I don't really care if it's a good idea, just if it's at all possible.

Now, on Windows, although I'd call WinMain, a non-UI (uh, windowless) program can still work through a messageloop. In this case, the main thread handles all messages that have their HWND parameter set to nullptr (the messages not sent to a specific window), and each window lives in its own thread, with its own wndproc called in its own message loop.

I believe a similar setup should be possible in X11, using a xcb_connection_t per thread (and thus per window). Assuming this is correct, what would be a good way of handling the "main" non-UI thread? If it does nothing, the program will exit immediately, regardless of how many other threads are running their X event loops. I'd like to keep this part X free. I've read about pause, sigsuspend etc. But I'm not sure these are the best fit for this somewhat simple purpose.

Comment: Sounds *very similar* to something I've been working on on the side for my own cross-platform effort. Maybe we can talk offline?

Comment: I have no doubt this is very similar to what everyone else is doing, but it's the details I need :P. Feel free to contact me through any channel listed on my profile. For reference, my effort is publicly visible as https://github.com/rubenvb/skui.